# How to get the index of an element in array in mongodb

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I am having a document with array object, like

```
{
_id:ObjectID(),
infoId:ObjectID(),
infos:[
{
created_at:  ISODate("2014-07-16T11:55:24.348Z"),
info:1
},
{
created_at:  ISODate("2014-07-16T11:58:45.185Z"),
info:2
},
{
created_at: ISODate("2014-07-16T12:17:12.182Z"),
info:3
},
{
created_at:  ISODate("2014-07-16T12:19:59.171Z"),
info:4
},
{
created_at: ISODate("2014-07-16T12:27:30.925Z"),
info:5
},
]
}
```

**From this document I want get the infos whose create_at is greater than say ISODate("2014-07-16T12:10:12.182Z") till end. Along with it I want to know the index of these retrieved records. **

In my example I want the result as :

```
[{
created_at: ISODate("2014-07-16T12:17:12.182Z"),
info:3
},
{
created_at:  ISODate("2014-07-16T12:19:59.171Z"),
info:4
},
{
created_at: ISODate("2014-07-16T12:27:30.925Z"),
info:5
}]
```

with some way to get the index too.

One way to get index is, if I stored index also along with created_at and info I will get. But I may delete specific records too, then for that case I need to update all the records after that again. SO I am not keeping index explicitly.

Comment: what would you need the index for? Do you want to delete the elements after?

Comment: Not only for delete. In client side I am not retrieving all at a time, as per need I will retrieve. SO for that I need index, from which I need to retrieve.

Comment: You cannot assign index dynamically to array elements, because arrays may change at any time. A better approach is probably to assign `id`s to your elements.